# wordpress wp-content/uploads folder 301 redirect to S3 bucket by cloudfrond CDN by .htaccess issues

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

See below, the .htacess file from Wordpress. If I remove the part starting from `# BEGIN WordPress`, all the image file URLs will be changed to `d28rt1vkpsdxas.cloudfront.net/someimage.png` successfully.

However, all the internal links will be unable to access (only the home page can access). The error is

> Not Found The requested URL /shop/ was not found on this server.

But if I keep the part start from `# BEGIN WordPress`, the CDN redirect will not work anymore. All photos are missing.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

Rewriterule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://exampled28t1vkps.cloudfront.net/$1 [r=301,nc]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing the [`[L]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag, which prevents other rules from redirecting:

```
Rewriterule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://exampled28t1vkps.cloudfront.net/$1 [r=301,nc,l]
```